# print file name and odd lines in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix, printing

I am trying to output(print) file name followed by the odd lines files in a directory.

What I want to output

```
linereader: line 1
linereader: line 3
lineareder2: q
lineareader2: e
```

What I am getting

```
linereader:
line 1
line 3
line 5
linereader2:
q
e
q
e
```

my code

```
for file in *; 
do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "$file": && sed -n 1~2p $file
    fi 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sed substitution:

```sh
for file in *; 
do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        sed -n "1~2s/.*/$file: &/p" $file
    fi 
done
```

This substitution is applied to odd lines, `1~2s`. It matches all the text in the line, `/.*/`, replaces it with the file name plus the matched text `/$file: &/`, and prints it to standard output `p`.

Comment: thank you so much!!!! would you mind explaining how that works? the sed substitution that is

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the cleanest (easiest to understand) way is:

```
echo $file
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 {print}' $file
```

This expresses your requirements nearly verbatim. `NR` holds the line number, and `%` is the modulus operator.